# <select> change event not fired when using keyboard

Tags: jquery, onchange

http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/

```
<select id="users">
<option value="1">jack</option>
<option value="2">brill</option>
<option value="3">antony</option>
</select>​
```

js:

```
$("#users").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})​
```

why change event not fired when using (keyup/keydown) until mouse is clicked

Comment: The change event is fired when the element loses focus. Change the value with the keyboard and press tab, and the change event will fire.

Comment: As of today it works; no need for keyup or any other event.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> why change event not fired when using (keyup/keydown) until mouse is clicked

It also fires when focus leaves the `select`. That's just how the `change` event works.

If you want proactive notification, you have to watch for `change` and `keydown` (at least, you may want `click` as well) and handle the case of getting an event when the value hasn't actually changed, **and** you have to handle the fact that some of those events (`keydown`, for instance) are fired *before* the value is changed, so you have to wait a moment before processing the event. Or see [SpYk3HH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9806323/157247) which uses `keyup` instead — that will be less proactive (not updating until key release, which could be desireable), but then you don't need the delay (`setTimeout`) my code below has.

Example ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/1/)):

HTML (I took the liberty of changing the values so it was clearer which went with each name):

```
<select id="users">
<option value="j">jack</option>
<option value="b">brill</option>
<option value="a">antony</option>
</select>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#users").bind("keydown change", function(){
    var box = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        display(box.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

---

Note in 2016: `bind` has largely been replaced with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on). In the above it you'd literally just replace "bind" with "on".

Comment: is there any way to fire it maybe repalce `change` by an other event

Comment: @mgraph: That's what I said: You need to at least add `keydown` (and handle the fact it fires before the value changes). See the example I just added.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, why not `keyup` then, which fires after the value change ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: You can do that. It makes the notification less proactive (which may be a good thing), but as you say, it avoids the issue with the delay. I upvoted SpYk3HH's answer for that very reason. :-)

Comment: ty for your support, lol. Also I updated mine to give another nice little func i use on selects to make them scroll forever. +1 to ya

Comment: For jQuery 1.7 and above, you can now use `.on('change keyup'...`

Comment: @rybo111: Yeah, four years later, things have changed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just put that there for people who find this on Google, like I did

Answer (score 18):

Try changing

```
$("#users").change(function(){
```

to

```
$("#users").bind('change keyup', function(e) {
```

that should bound yyour function for both, onchange event and when down or up arrow key is pressed

note, you could also use keydown, but it may not preform as expected as your code will run before the select change is made

And in case you want an infinate scrolling Select box, i have a nifty little func i wrote that so far, for me at least, works perfect and can be assigned all on its own without affecting other keyup actions, of course, and with intent on our sight, this is ment to work on the keyup, and so you still have to actually press the arrow key over and over, but it will continue to loop non stop through all options.  Although, im pretty sure it'll work with keydown too, but we dont use it that way, so i've not tested it.  Again, keydown, may not perform as intended, especially if the select only has 2 or 3 options.

```
function selectInfinateScroll() {
    if ($(this).data("lastSelected")) {
        if ($(this).data("lastSelected")[0] == $(this).children("option:selected")[0]) {
            if ($(this).children("option:selected").index() == 0) {
                $(this).children("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
                $(this).children("option:last-child").prop("selected", true).change();
            }
            else {
                $(this).children("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
                $(this).children("option:first-child").prop("selected", true).change();
            };
        };
    };
    $(this).data("lastSelected", $(this).children("option:selected"));
}

$(function() {
    //  Enable 'Scrolling Through' on Select Boxes
    $("select").keyup(selectInfinateScroll);
});
```

---

### UPDATED!

---

I'm leaving the original answer, as it uses an alternate method that may be more useful to some. However, I have come up with both a shorter function that works on "keydown" and a jQuery plugin using said function that allows user to "hold down" and arrow key and still sort through options infinitely!

First, the new function

```
function keydownInfiniteSelect(e) {
    var eKey = e.which || e.key,
        selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    if (eKey == 38 && selected.is(":first-child")) {    //    up arro
        $(this).find("option").last().prop("selected", true);    //    set value to last option
        $(this).change();    //    ensure select triggers change do to return false
        return false;    //    keeps select from skipping to second last option
    }
    else if (eKey == 40 && selected.is(":last-child")) {    //    down arro
        $(this).val($(this).find("option").first().val());    //    set value to first option
        $(this).change();    //    ensure select triggers change
        return false;    //    keeps select from skipping to second option
    }
}
```

Use like: `$("select").keydown(keydownInfiniteSelect);`

And the jQuery Plugin Style!

```
(function($){$.infiniteSelect||($.extend({infiniteSelect:function(b){return b.each(function(){$(this).data("infiniteSelect")||($.fn.on?$(this).on("keydown",$.infiniteSelect.methods.keydownInfiniteSelect).data("infiniteSelect",!0):$(this).bind("keydown",$.infiniteSelect.methods.keydownInfiniteSelect).data("infiniteSelect",!0))})}}),$.fn.extend({infiniteSelect:function(){return $.infiniteSelect($(this))}}),$.infiniteSelect.methods={keydownInfiniteSelect:function(b){b=b.which||b.key;var c=$(this).find("option:selected");
if(38==b&&c.is(":first-child"))return $(this).find("option").last().prop("selected",!0),$(this).change(),!1;if(40==b&&c.is(":last-child"))return $(this).val($(this).find("option").first().val()),$(this).change(),!1}})})(jQuery);
```

Use as `$("select").infiniteSelect()` *OR* `$.infiniteSelect("select")`

### jsFiddle of Plugin <sub>Mini</sub>fied




### Uncut Plugin Fiddle

PS. I almost have a Vanilla JavaScript ready for the function except that the "set to last option" part of the method keeps dieing, or going null, or skipping to the second to last. I just can't seem to get it to set correctly. If anyone wants to fix it and update, I'd be much obliged. See [***HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/bXeDD/3/)

Comment: I think the first version of this answer used `keydown` without a caveat. *I* wouldn't have downvoted for that without comment, but... As the answer stands now, seems like a perfectly good option and avoids the delay issue my answer has. +1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.. using `keyup` is better than introducing a time delay. The former is designed to work as the OP wanted, and the latter is sort of a hack that can cause a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

That is the normal behaviour ...

Quoting the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)

> **change**
>       The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answers above I was able to get the behaviour I needed using:

```
$( "select" ).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    $(  '#' + e.target.id ).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#users").bind('change keyup', function(e) {
```

was enough

Answer (score -1):

```
/*After having been searching for hours i wrote my own. */



<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/
        jQuery('.dropedZip').html('' +
        '<select name="theName" id="theID" size="4" style="width: 184px" >' +
        '<option value="A">Choice A</option>' +
        '<option value="B">Choice B</option>' +
        '<option value="C">Choice C</option>' +
        '<option value="D">Choice D</option>' +
        '</select>');

        var nextOptValue = 0;
        var prevOptValue = 0;

        jQuery('#prop').keydown(function (e) {

            var key = e.which;
            if(key==13){
                var currOptValue = jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').val();// CURRENT
                alert('ausgesucht: '+currOptValue);
            }
            /* UP */
            if(key==38){
                var currOptValue = jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').val();// CURRENT
                if(currOptValue!=undefined){// CURRENT != undefined ?
                    prevOptValue = jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').prev('option').val();// PREV
                    if(prevOptValue!=undefined){// PREV != undefined ?
                        jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').removeAttr('selected');// REMOVE CURRENT
                        jQuery('select#theID > option[value='+prevOptValue+']').prop('selected',true);// SET PREV
                        jQuery('input#prop').val(prevOptValue);// SET INPUT VALUE : OTHER
                    }
                }
            }
            /* DOWN */
            if(key==40){
                if(jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').val()==undefined){// NULL
                    nextOptValue = jQuery('select#theID > option:first').val();// FIRST
                    jQuery('select#theID > option[value='+nextOptValue+']').prop('selected',true);// SET FIRST
                    jQuery('input#prop').val(nextOptValue);// SET INPUT VALUE : FIRST
                }else{
                    nextOptValue = jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').next('option').val();// NEXT
                    jQuery('select#theID > option:selected').removeAttr('selected');// REMOVE FIRST
                    jQuery('select#theID > option[value='+nextOptValue+']').prop('selected',true);// SET NEXT
                    jQuery('input#prop').val(nextOptValue);// SET INPUT VALUE : OTHER
                }

            }

        });
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/
        /*********** SELECT PLZ ****************/


    });
</script>

        <input id="prop" type="text">
<div class="dropedZip"></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to comment. So as output you have only one INPUT field und below SELECT with four OPTIONS. You focus the mouse on the INPUT field and then you are able to push the UP and DOWN key on your keyboard. Your OPTIONS will be switched up and down. With the ENTER key it reads out  current VALUE of selected OPTION. I hope it helps somebody.