# jQuery: Infinite scrolling Select Box

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am trying to make a better function of something I once answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806257/select-change-event-not-fired-when-using-keyboard/9806323#9806323), however I'm running into a bit of a snag I don't quite understand. I wanted to be able to use "keydown" to allow a user to "hold the up/down arrow key" and keep scrolling through options. The odd part is that, while it functions as intended within the "keydown", as you will see in the fiddle, by the time it reaches "keyup" the value is set to the prev/next option of the first/last, respectively.

To get a better idea of what I mean, please explore the following:

### jsFiddle




#### Slightly Alternate Approach

 <sub>same result</sub>

```
$("select").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var eKey = e.which || e.key,
        selected = $(this).find("option:selected");

    if (eKey == 38 && selected.is(":first")) {    //    up arro
        $(this).val($(this).find("option").last().val());
    }
    else if (eKey == 40 && selected.is(":last")) {    //    down arro
        $(this).val($(this).find("option").first().val());
    }
})
```

It looks to me like it should work just fine, but of course, it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFtbZ/)

`return false` after you loop the selected item.

```
$("select").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var eKey = e.which || e.key,
        selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    console.log($(this).val());

    if (eKey == 38 && selected.is(":first")) {    //    up arro
        $(this).find("option").last().prop("selected", true);
        return false;
    }
    else if (eKey == 40 && selected.is(":last")) {    //    down arro
        selected.prop("selected", false);
        $(this).find("option:first").prop("selected", true);
        return false;
    }
    console.log("end keydown", $(this).val());
})
.on("keyup", function(e) {
    console.log("keyup", e.which, $(this).val());
});

$("*").click(function(e) { $("select").focus() });
```

Otherwise you are looping it and then the browser's default behavior is triggering.

---

For those interested, final result:


### jsFiddle


Also, see jQuery Plugin of this!


### jsFiddle

Comment: Hmm. Not where I can test this right now, but a few thoughts; 1.) There isn't a loop in play "that I see" (check console, singlton firing), 2.) Won't this stop the ability to "hold" an arrow key?

Comment: Finally a chance to test, and no, this doesnt break the "hold" ability and does seem to work! tho i'm still not sure where it's a "loop fault". I'd really like to see a more in depth explination if you or anyone has one. Thank you!

Comment: @SpYk3HH When you press the down arrow while focused on a select box, the keydown event fires and all event handlers are queued up. Your custom event handler is handled first followed by the default handler which select the next option in the given direction. If your handler does *not* `return false` then the second event handler is evaluated and select the next option: the 2nd or 4th depending on direction. If you *do* `return false` then the following event handlers are cancelled.