# KendoDropDownList 'select' event not firing when using keyboard

Tags: events, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

This is similar to the question here - [<select> change event not fired when using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9806257/95012)

I am looking for a KendoUI specific answer.

Using the KendoDropDownList (and KendoComboBox, KendoAutoComplete, etc.) the 'select' event only fires when a user uses the mouse to select an item from the popup list.

I find this very counter-intuitive, is there a provided fix, workaround or other solution for this?

Comment: Was my solution what you were looking for?

Comment: @ryan - thanks for your answer I haven't forgotten it :) and I will give it the attention it deserves as soon as I can ...

Comment: in case anyone's wondering if this question/answer applies to fixing the issue where arrow keys no longer work with kendoDropDownList, it absolutely does. it wasn't clear to me if the select event not firing was the issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is expanded, using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key fires the `select` event. To expand the list via keyboard use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. If you want the arrow keys to fire it, you would have to trigger the `select` event as part of the change event.

```
var ddl, $log;

$(function () {
    $log = $('#log');
    ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        change: onChange,
        select: onSelect
    }).data('kendoDropDownList');
});

function onChange(e) {
    $log.prepend("<div>event :: change (" + this.text() + ' : ' + this.value() + ")</div>" );
    ddl.trigger('select');
}

function onSelect(e) {
    $log.prepend("<div>event :: select (" + this.text() + ' : ' + this.value() + ")</div>" );
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LtdLc/)**